# mypy: Untyped decorator makes function "my_method" untyped

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy

When I try using a decorator that I defined in another package, mypy fails with the error message `Untyped decorator makes function "my_method" untyped`. How should I define my decorator to make sure this passes?

```
from mypackage import mydecorator

@mydecorator
def my_method(date: int) -> str:
   ...
```

Comment: I failed to reproduce the error message. Please provide the code of `decorator`.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? As the message says, the issue is that the decorator is untyped – the obvious solution is to type it. What problem do you have doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `mypy` documentation contains the [section](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#declaring-decorators) describing the declaration of decorators for functions with an arbitrary signature.

An example from there:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar, Tuple, cast

F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])

# A decorator that preserves the signature.
def my_decorator(func: F) -> F:
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        print("Calling", func)
        return func(*args, **kwds)
    return cast(F, wrapper)

# A decorated function.
@my_decorator
def foo(a: int) -> str:
    return str(a)

a = foo(12)
reveal_type(a)  # str
foo('x')    # Type check error: incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

Comment: good answer, but you should update it to use new ParamSpec approach, which is detailed in the link you gave yo the mypy docs