# FastAPI router type error: "Untyped decorator males function untyped"

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, fastapi

I'm building an API with FastAPI. I want the API to be type-safe, but running mypy on a route returns this error: `"Untyped decorator males function 'get_overview' untyped"`. Here's my route:

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/overview/{location_id}")
async def get_overview(location_id: str) -> object:
    if 4 not in fake_items_db:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Item not found")
    return overview
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621789/mypy-untyped-decorator-makes-function-my-method-untyped) post provides a solution to the error, but doesn't work with the `router` API.

Is there a FastAPI-specific solution to this error?