# Error: Untyped decorator (@typeguard) makes function "add_two" untyped [misc]

Tags: python, mypy, typing, typeguards

### Context

While using [typeguard](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard/issues/60) on a project with `mypy`, I've encountered the error:

```
src/pythontemplate/adder.py:6: error: Untyped decorator makes function "add_two" untyped  [misc]
```

on the following example code:

```py
"""Example python file with a function."""

from typeguard import typechecked


@typechecked
def add_two(*, x: int) -> int:
    """Adds a value to an incoming number."""
    return x + 2
```

After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65641392/7437143) answer, it seems one can resolve this error message by manually adding a typing for the `@typechecked` function/decorator.

### Issue

1. I did not quite determine what the typing should be for the `@typeguard` decorator.
2. This decorator is in each `python` file in the project, so adding the typing for that decorator in each file, or even an import to a separate file with that typing, would be quite a bit of duplicate code and/or boilerplate code.
3. This decorator is specifically for typechecking, so I would expect there may be a more elegant fashion to resolve this issue.

### Question

How can one ensure the `@typeguard` decorator is typed?

Comment: [`typechecked` seems to be typed, though...](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard/blob/c520405a64eeb4c8c363526050af4da98202f073/src/typeguard/_decorators.py#L111-L121) are you using the most recent version of `typeguard`?

Comment: @AKX, thank you, I am using the must recent stable/pypi version, version [2.13.3](https://pypi.org/project/typeguard/) which does not seem to [contain](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard/releases/tag/2.13.3) the `_decorators.py` file that you link to. I will force `typeguard` to a more recent/beta/unstable version, and try again. After trying all 4 `3.x` versions, pre-commit still threw the same error. To verify: `pip list` says: `typeguard          3.0.0rc2`.

Comment: Maybe ask in `typeguard`'s issues then..?

Answer (score 0):

I falsely assumed mypy would look inside the activated conda environment in which the `pre-commit run --all` command was ran, to find which `typeguard` version was available for usage. That assumption was invalid.

As pointed out by agronholm [here](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard/issues/308#issuecomment-1457008300), I had to specify `typeguard` as a mypy dependency inside the `.pre-commit-config.yaml`. So after changing:

```yaml
 - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-
   rev: v1.1.1
   hooks:
    - id: mypy
      # args: ["--disallow-untyped-calls", "--disallow-untyped-defs"]
      args: ["--strict"]
```

to:

```yaml
 - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
### - repo: https://github.com/a-t-0/mypy
   rev: v1.1.1
   hooks:
    - id: mypy
      # args: ["--disallow-untyped-calls", "--disallow-untyped-defs"]
      args: ["--strict"]
      additional_dependencies:
            - typeguard
```

The issue was resolved!