# mypy errors with decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy

```
class Cell(ABC):
    def __init__(self, value: int | None = None):
        ...

    @property
    def value(self) -> int | None:
        return self._value


class InputCell(Cell):
    @Cell.value.setter
    def value(self, value: int) -> None:
        ...
```

Running mypy with `--strict` generates:

```
react.py:28: error: "Callable[[Cell], int | None]" has no attribute "setter"  [attr-defined]
react.py:28: error: Untyped decorator makes function "value" untyped  [misc]
```

Line 28 happens to be the `@Cell.value.setter`.
I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65641392/839733) that uses `cast` in a custom decorator, but in my case, I don't have a custom decorator. How do I get rid of these errors?

Edit:

It appears that there's an [open ticket](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1465) for the first error that has been open for 7 years now!!!

Comment: @nicomp You only had to read the question. "_Line 28 happens to be the @Cell.value.setter_"

Comment: @nicomp I suspect you have too high bar for SO questions. Only missing `ABC` import (presumably `from abc import ABC`) is a real minor problem here (it's stl, so not critical). "Line 28" is clearly explained later. It could be improved, of course, by adjusting these numbers manually or running `mypy` on clean MRE, but this question *does* provide an almost good MRE and explains the problem clearly. This code can be pasted into [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=0203c64b4e483d07e69749856376f7d4) and run as-is (after restoring missing import).

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar please post your "edit" as answer, since your findings do actually answer your question. "No, you can't due to documented limitation" is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @STerliakov My edit explains the  first error but not the second. I couldn’t find anything that does.

Comment: The second is just a consequence of the first: your decorator is `Any` for `mypy` after this resolution failure (it's coded as `from_error` `Any` type in `mypy` source). It's equivalent to `deco: Any`; `@deco` `def value(self, value: int) -> None: ...`